# IE doesn't render elements with linear-gradient CSS

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, css

```
#botton{        

        background: linear-gradient(top, #6de37d 0%, #68d574 100%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6de37d 0%, #68d574 100%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6de37d 0%, #68d574 100%);
        }
```

IE 9 just doesn't show this element. I found out solution for IE 10, but is there anything I can do here?

And how I can just write CSS for this button only for IE with non-gradient background?

Comment: See this article: http://css3wizardry.com/2010/10/29/css-gradients-for-ie9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will add gradient to IE.
IE9 does not support linear gradient.

An example:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=1, startColorstr='#6de37d', endColorstr='#68d574'); /* for IE */
```

Comment: Where should I add this? HTML file, CSS?

Comment: beneath the rest of you css gradients

Answer (score 3):

IE9 does not support CSS gradients; that feature was only introduced in IE10.

There are a number of work-arounds involving the `-ms-filter` style or an SVG data image embedded in the CSS code, but to be honest I've found that the best results are from using the [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com/) polyfill, which allows you to use standard CSS code for gradients even in older IE versions.

If you really don't want to use CSS3Pie, then I suggest using one of the many CSS Gradient Generator pages on the web to create the code for you; there's a lot of caveats you need to be aware of, and it's a lot easier to let them generate the code for you rather than trying to piece it together yourself. [Here's one site you could use](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). (there are others though)